# Scroll up a div instead of scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Weyoo, I have a div that appears when i right click, but the problem is it scrolls down like in this image:

[image]

But i would rather to scroll up like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
$("#Menu-File").finish().toggle(100).

      css({
          top: event.pageY + "px",
          left: event.pageX + "px"
      });
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my awful Paint mechanics.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help

Comment: Done, code changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i have found the solution,

```
$("#Menu-File").finish().slideToggle(

      css({
          bottom: "calc(100% - " + event.pageY + "px)",
          left: event.pageX + "px"
      });
```